# Extract geometries from bounding box (within and overlapping) and copy results to new empty database

Tags: postgresql, openstreetmap, postgis, jts

I am new to PostgreSQL and GIS.

I do have a downloaded dump of *OSM data* (map of Germany) available, which was imported via osm2pgsql into a *PostGIS-enabled PostgreSQL* database ***germanyPG***.

The query

```
SELECT PostGIS_Full_Version();
```

returns

```
POSTGIS="2.3.3 r15473" 
GEOS="3.6.1-CAPI-1.10.1 r4317" 
PROJ="Rel. 4.9.1, 04 March 2015" 
GDAL="GDAL 2.2.1, released 2017/06/23" 
LIBXML="2.7.8" LIBJSON="0.12"
```

I also have an empty PostGIS-enabled PostgreSQL database ***subsetGermanyPG*** available which has same properties (database schema, structure, tables, columns, indexes, etc.) as ***germanyPG*** database.

**Question 1:**

Once I've given the coordinates of a rectangle (see Figure 1).
How can I query the ***germanyPG*** database to get all objects that lie within that given rectangle or overlap with the rectangle (especially those that are much larger than the rectangle) and enclose it (see Figure 2)?

Figure 1: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ZOqJ.jpg

Figure 2: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEnvP.jpg

I am not sure whether *ST_Intersects* in combination with *ST_MakeEnvelope* (minLong, minLat, maxLong, max Lat, srid) will do the job because I don't have an idea how to verify the query results...

```
SELECT realname
FROM domain 
WHERE ST_Intersects(ST_MakeEnvelope(11.5, 49.8, 12.0, 50.1, 4326), 
                    geom:: GEOMETRY);
```

**Question 2:**

What is the most elegant way to copy this queried results from ***germanyPG*** database into the second database ***subsetGermanyPG***? Notice that both databases are on the same remote host system (server side) and I need to use a JAVA JTS application (client side) who 'coordinates' respectively does the copy job.

I know that I could use JAVA to query the ***germanyPG*** database and afterward store the results of the query in a JAVA datatype (maybe one or more arrays?) and finally insert these data sequentially in ***subsetGermanyPG*** database.

But what if the query is extensive (multiple GBs) and needs a long time. I think such extreme cases would result in network traffic issues, main memory leaks, and so on.

So I hope there is a more resource-saving solution out there?

**Please note, that I am only allowed to use JAVA standard library inclusive JTS.**

Answer (score 2):

For your first question, it sounds like you are looking to convince yourself that your method is working.  For that, I'd suggest using QGIS to map the results of your query.

For the second question, it sounds like an easier solution would to be populate the second table from a query on the first.  As an example, see something like this https://www.mkyong.com/database/postgresql-create-table-from-exisiting-table/ .